# Can't pull back more than 2k rows from Saved Reports using Lightning

Tags: lightning, salesforce-classic

Are there differences between the Reports API in Lightning and Classic?

When one of our users using Classic pulls a Saved Report we get all the rows. When they are using Lightning and pull a Saved Report we only get 2k rows.

Comment: other user has the same permissions as you, or same profile / role ? And I wouldn't fetch that many at once, and try using `LIMIT` in query

Comment: @MacA. same user I toggle it back and forth. We are trying to load in the whole saved report, what kinds of limit queries would you use to paginate it?

Comment: Did Salesforce just push this problem to all saved reports? Classic and Lightning? Everything broke for us today.

Answer (score 1):

It's a salesforce limitation, Refer [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rd_reports_limits.htm&type=5)

> The API returns up to the first 2,000 report rows.

Comment: Thanks. From the link it says 'Available in: Salesforce Classic (not available in all orgs) and Lightning Experience' but the experience is different in lightning and classic?